# Fast, Cheap, and Good - Choose any Two

Tags: code-golf, counting

As programmers, we all know the saying: "You can have it fast and good, but it won't be cheap, you can have it cheap and good, but it won't be fast, or you can have it fast and cheap, but it won't be good."

For this challenge, you are implementing an imaginary configuration tool for your custom programming services. You should render a set of three check boxes, with a heading of "SELECT ANY TWO":

```
SELECT ANY TWO  
☐ FAST  
☐ CHEAP  
☐ GOOD
```

Once two items have been selected, the third item must be disabled. Upon deselecting one of the two selected items, all options must again be enabled. Put another way, if zero or one items are selected, all are still enabled, but if two items are selected, the third must be disabled.

No special controls allowed. The check boxes should be the standard check box in your language of choice. For example, don't use a "CheckBoxList" control, if your language has one. I'm imagining most entries will be HTML/jQuery, but that is not a rule. This is code golf, looking for the shortest entry.

**WINNERS SO FAR**

I'll break it down into categories. There are some clear winners:

**jQuery:**
[nderscore, Mr. Tenacity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two/26822#26822) Under 100b when you exclude text "resources". Honorable mention should also go to Matt for introducing the jQuery concepts that many took inspiration from.

**Dyalog APL:**
[marinus, a.k.a. Mr. Unicode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26789/21186) How do you type all those things? I can see why you would want to write short programs.

**PHP:**
[SuperScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26825/21186) I believe this is the shortest entry that actually disables rather than deselecting the third option, following the strictest interpretation of the rules.

Comment: Can I just make it so that only two can be selected at a time? So that selecting the third de-selects one of the other ones? Or perhaps add an accept button that gets greyed out if 3 options are selected?

Comment: @Quincunx - Since there is no heuristic (outside of mind-reading) that could decide which one to deselect, this would confuse the user... so I'll have to say no, because we don't want the first impression of our custom software services to be a bad one. ;)

Comment: This question interested me in Python 3's tkinter, so I am trying to learn that now. IMO, the best way to learn GUI is by trial and error. I tried this: http://ideone.com/YHLZIQ . Result: rapid opening of new GUIs. I had to open task manager to close them. :-). Image (the number soon climbed to 340: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c9wQi.png)

Comment: The bonus contest should be another question as there is no objective primary winning criterion or any description of the "bonus". It said that code should be "...elegant and flexible..." and "...concise and clear..." which is against [tag:code-golf]. VTC as unclear what you are asking. Please don't radically change questions long after they are asked.

Comment: Fair enough, removed.

Comment: @BrucePierson Actually, there is. We could deselect the oldest selected checkbox. However, the code for that would be much more than the code you require.

Comment: @Quincunx Well, no question that your suggestion fits the precise definition of "heuristic" - certain parts of the definition, anyway. :)

Comment: Is it permitted to prevent the user from checking the 3rd checkbox instead of actually disabling it?

Comment: @nderscore [yes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two?noredirect=1#comment59369_26786).

Comment: What do you mean by "*Don't use a check box list*"? If you applied this too strictly, one wouldn't even be allowed to use jQuery.

Comment: "Do not use these controls for SQLite."

Comment: I've been having a discussion on meta, are the requirements for this challenge to write a function or a fully functional program? http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1550

Comment: @iamkrillin I think all the entries so far are executable in their context. Obviously a framework of some kind is usually present (browser, Qt, etc.). But it must display the page/form and allow interaction.

Comment: If something is good and cheap, it won't be fast. Therefore it won't be cheap either.

Comment: <anal>"Pick two" sounds much better than "Select any two"

Comment: Would we be allowed to simply have `SELECT ANY TWO` be the title of the window, rather than a label inside?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Javascript (*ES5*) with jQuery - 143 ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/69Ted/))

I modified [Matt's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26785/20160) and golfed it as far down as I think it can go:

```js
$("*").html(["SELECT ANY TWO","FAST","GOOD","CHEAP"].join("<input type=checkbox onclick=(a=$('input:not(:checked)')).prop('disabled',!a[1])>"))
```

## Javascript (*ES5*) without jQuery - <strike>185</strike> 175 ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/bCjn4/))

Using jQuery is kind of cheating, so here's a solution without it:

```js
(d=document).write(["SELECT ANY TWO","FAST","GOOD","CHEAP"].join("<input type=checkbox onclick='for(b in a=d.querySelectorAll(\"input:not(:checked)\"))a[b].disabled=!a[1]'>"))
```

---

If we're allowed to prevent the user from checking the 3rd box instead of actually disabling the field, we can make it even shorter:

## With jQuery - <strike>126</strike> 123 ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/xfj7U/))

```js
$("*").html(["SELECT ANY TWO","FAST","GOOD","CHEAP"].join("<input type=checkbox onclick=this.checked*=!$(':checked')[2]>"))
```

## Without jQuery - <strike>150</strike> 147 ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/7W3pG/))

```js
(d=document).write(["SELECT ANY TWO","FAST","GOOD","CHEAP"].join("<input type=checkbox onclick=this.checked*=!d.querySelectorAll(':checked')[2]>"))
```

Comment: Cool.  Using `.join` is a good trick!

Comment: `"SELECT ANY TWO0FAST0GOOD0CHEAP".replace(/0/g,` is another way to do it resulting in the same length.

Comment: just being picky, the jquery version should use prop, not attr

Comment: @Einacio your wish is my command!

Comment: (Y) if it is with the same char lenght, why not promote good practices, right?

Comment: Nice work. Agreed on the `.join`, great approach.

Comment: @Einacio But codegolf is about worst practices! :P

Comment: @nderscore is officially at 99b with jQuery once you take out the required text "resources". That is going to be tough to top!

Comment: The second solution doesn't work if you use the keyboard to check the checkbox, does it?

Comment: @JanDvorak pressing spacebar while the checkbox is in focus does trigger a click event, so it works.

Answer (score 28):

## JavaScript - <strike>184</strike> 169 (with jQuery)

```javascript
b="input",a="<input type=checkbox>",c=":checked";$("body").html("SELECT ANY TWO"+a+"FAST"+a+"GOOD"+a+"CHEAP").click(function(){$(b).not(c).attr("disabled",!!$(b+c)[1])})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L33JK/16/

EDIT: improved with help from @Daniel Lisik - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26805/16278

Comment: Nice! Not enough rep to upvote... but you're hired!

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I'm learning. The cleverness of the variable assignment inside a jQuery selector. Very cool. Also, could you explain what the "double bang" (!!) is doing?

Comment: The single bang, coerces a boolean value, and double will obviously invert that. `undefined` coerces to true. That and the variable assignment are probably the only little tricks used really.

Comment: Your code can be reduced to 179 characters like this: `a="<input type='checkbox'>",b="input",c=":checked",$("body").html("SELECT ANY TWO"+a+"FAST"+a+"GOOD"+a+"CHEAP").change(function(){$(b+":not("+c+")").attr("disabled",!!$(b+c)[1])})` http://jsfiddle.net/L33JK/15/

Comment: Even less in the comment I left on yours, 169!

Comment: if you're defining b=input, can't you make `a = "<"+b+" type=checkbox>"`?

Comment: @Charles you can, but there won't be any difference in character length, (`#+b+"` is 5 characters and so is `input`).

Comment: Hey, nice solution! You can save two more bytes using `!!$(c)[1]` as `:checked` should only apply the `<input>`s anyway!

Comment: 143: http://jsfiddle.net/_nderscore/69Ted/

Comment: since the `input`s are the only elements, you can set `b='*'` and it'll work the same

Comment: @Einacio the body tag will be captured by `*` as well

Comment: @nderscore so? that only means the body will be set a disabled attribute that doesn't affect it. also, only `!!$(c)[1]` is needed, since `:checked` only filters the checkbox. speed is not important here

Comment: It only matters in my 143 solution above. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 12):

### Dyalog APL (on Windows) (169)

This is a static function, to test it if you don't know APL, type `)ed C` and paste this in the edit window, then run `C`.

```
C
'R'⎕WC'Form' 'Select any two',2/⊂S←2/20
1 21 41{('R.',⊃⍵)⎕WC'Button'⍵(⍺1)S'Check'('Event' 'Select' 'F')}¨'Fast' 'Cheap' 'Good'
B←R.(F C G)
F←{B.Active←X∨2≠+/X←B.State}
```

Newer bits of APL have *long* keywords. I still beat HTML though.

Explanation:

- `'R'⎕WC'Form' 'Select any two',2/⊂S←2/20`: create a form `R`, with title *Select any two* and size and position `20 20`. Also stores `20 20` in `S`.
- `1 21 41{`...`}¨'Fast' 'Cheap' 'Good'`: for each of these pairs of data (name and y-coordinate, which are the only variables that differ between the checkboxes:

  - `('R.',⊃⍵)⎕WC'Button'`: create a button within `R` with the first letter of the name,
  - `⍵(⍺1)S'Check'`: with the right argument as the title, `(left arg, 1)` as position, reusing `S` as the size and `Check` as style,
  - `('Event' 'Select' 'F')`, which calls the function `F` when clicked.
- `B←R.(F C G)`: use `B` as an abbreviation for the three checkboxes we created
- `F←{`...`}`: define the callback function as:

  - `X←B.State`: get the state for each checkbox and store them in `X`,
  - `X∨2≠+/X`: sum X, if this is not equal to two all checkboxes must be active, if it is equal to two only checked checkboxes must be active
  - `B.Active←`: enable or disable the checkboxes

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## Python <s>3</s> 2, <s>454</s> <s>434</s> ... <s>393</s> 392 bytes

I thought, *Python must be shorter than Java.* Here is the "proof" (<s>*EDIT:* now it really is shorter</s>):

```python
from Tkinter import*
t=Tk()
r=str.replace
exec r(r(r(r('a@b@c@l=Label(t,text="SELECT ANY TWO");A`FAST|a);B`CHEAP|b);C`GOOD|c);l^A^B^C^','`','=Checkbutton(t,text="'),'|','",v='),'^','.pack();'),'@','=IntVar();')
def f(p,b,B,s):
 for i in 0,1,2:
    y=b[i].get()
    if p[i]-y:
     p[i]=y;s-=1
     if p[i]:s>0and B[i].toggle();s+=2
 t.after(1,f,p,b,B,s)
t.after(1,f,[0]*3,[a,b,c],[A,B,C],0)
t.mainloop()
```

For those of you curious as to what the `exec` expression actually executes, it executes this (this is what the replaces do to the string. Newlines added for readability):

```python
a=IntVar();
b=IntVar();
c=IntVar();
l=Label(t,text="SELECT ANY TWO");
A=Checkbutton(t,text="FAST",v=a);
B=Checkbutton(t,text="CHEAP",v=b);
C=Checkbutton(t,text="GOOD",v=c);
l.pack();
A.pack();
B.pack();
C.pack();
```

This uses the same logic as my Java answer: unselect the checkbox if it causes more than 2 checkboxes to be selected. <s>Unf</s> <s>Fortunately</s> Unfortunately, I spent <s>more</s> <s>less</s> more bytes doing this.

[image]

**EDITS:**

1. massive adjustment of code to use `exec`, saving a whopping 1 byte!
2. switched to python 2 to squeeze two bytes from the `exec` (removing parentheses).
3. more golfing. Includes changing `range(3)` to `0,1,2` and changing the indentation to have one layer of tabs. Unsure if `\t\t` would work instead of `\t__`(`_` is the space character). Finally reached the longest my Java answer ever was.
4. used [replace trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26834/9498)
5. used [Bakiru's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two#comment59602_26790), and golfed some more. Actually made it shorter than Java! But now, the Java answer got golfed more, so this is again longer. :-(
6. used [improved replace trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27044/9498).
7. changed a `!=` for a `-`.

Comment: Interesting approach. +1

Comment: I can cheat with the turbo mode on my keyboard. First, I check two boxes. Second, I use Tab to highlight the third. Now I hold Space Bar in turbo mode for a few seconds. Sometimes, this checks the third box!

Comment: @kernigh I believe that is because my code gets to the point where it knows that the box has been toggled, but the code hasn't reached the point where it re-toggles the box. So if you toggle the box in that time (to off), my code will put a checkmark on it.

Comment: You can avoid the indented block starting with `if p[i]` using an `and` instead of an `if`: `if p[i]:s>1 and B[i].toggle();s+=1`.

Comment: @kernigh I was wrong; replacing `B[i].toggle()` with `B[i].deselect()` doesn't change anything. I have no idea why this is so. Perhaps it is a flaw with `tkinter`

Answer (score 10):

## Java, <s>421</s> ... <s>369</s> 351 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;class F extends Checkbox{F(String s){super(s);}public static void main(String[]a){new Frame(){{add(new Panel(){{add(new Label("SELECT ANY TWO"));F[]c={new F("FAST"),new F("CHEAP"),new F("GOOD")};for(F b:c){add(b);b.addItemListener(e->{int x=0;for(F d:c)x+=d.getState()?1:0;if(x>2)((F)e.getSource()).setState(1<0);});}}});}}.show();}}
```

Java... because Java. Nicer looking code:

```java
import java.awt.*;

class F extends Checkbox {
    F(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        new Frame() {
            {
                add(new Panel() {
                    {
                        add(new Label("SELECT ANY TWO"));
                        F[] c = {new F("FAST"), new F("CHEAP"), new F("GOOD")};
                        for (F b: c) {
                            add(b);
                            b.addItemListener(e -> {
                                int x = 0;
                                for (F d: c) {
                                    x += d.getState() ? 1 : 0;
                                }
                                if (x > 2) ((F) e.getSource()).setState(1 < 0);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }.show();
    }
}
```

Sample run (different sizings of the window, first is on startup):

[image]
[image]
[image]

The checkboxes are arranged horizontally; [this is allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two/26786#comment59367_26786). It would take much more to align it properly. Also, [I'm disabling by unchecking the box when it is clicked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two/26786#comment59369_26786), not by making it impossible to be clicked.

**EDITS:**

1. saved 3 bytes by making the main class extend `Checkbox`.
2. reread [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) and realized that the type name was unnecessary. Take that Python!
3. converted a `while` loop to a foreach loop (thanks [Lee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two#comment59876_26786)); why didn't I think of that before?
4. saved 18 bytes by using an anonymous class and an instance initalizer for both the `Frame` and `Panel`.

Comment: No restriction on the alignment (so I suppose Matt could reduce his by 5 characters). Props for a complete running program... but I don't see that the third option is disabled.

Comment: @BrucePierson It is disabled. It cannot be clicked. If it is clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. You're immediately "unsetting" the checked state without disabling? That would be acceptable.

Comment: @BrucePierson That's right. To actually disable, I'd have to change `if(x>2)((Checkbox)e.getSource()).setState(1<0);` to `if(x>2){Checkbox b=(Checkbox)e.getSource();b.setState(1<0);b.setEnabled(1<0);}`

Comment: That works. Thanks for the edit on the OP, by the way - looks much better. :)

Comment: @BrucePierson Whenever you think, *This looks funny* when it has to do with using a character representation of some graphical thing, look for unicode. Alternatively, for graphical design things, turn to [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask "Click on UI Wireframe or type CTRL-M"): http://i.stack.imgur.com/xFkzy.png

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by getting rid of the spaces around the equals signs for variables f and p.

Comment: @corsiKa Thanks. I usually miss some stuff like that when I shrink my code. I need to write an auto-golfer (preferably a regular expression that I can run in Netbeans with replace) that does that for me.

Comment: You could replace the `while(i<3){x+=c[i++].getState()?1:0;}` with `for(F d:c){x+=d.getState()?1:0;}` which would save a few characters.

Comment: I'd do `Arrays.stream(new F("FAST"), new F("CHEAP"), new F("GOOD")).foreach(/*stuff*/)` to save some more code.

Comment: Why `1<0` and not just `false`?

Comment: @SimonKuang `1<0` is 3 chars. `false` is 5. And your other suggestion is longer.

Comment: Sadly, `if(java.util.Arrays.stream(c).allMatch(F::getState))` is longer than `int x=0;for(F d:c)x+=d.getState()?1:0;if(x>2)`

Answer (score 10):

## Rebol, <strike>219</strike> 197

```
load-gui p: func[p][p/state/value]x: func[v][if all[p a p b p c][set-face v false]] view [title"SELECT ANY TWO"a: check"FAST"on-action[x a]b: check"CHEAP"on-action[x b]c: check"GOOD"on-action[x c]]
```

Ungolfed:

```
load-gui    ;; this is temporary while r3-gui is in beta

p: func [p] [p/state/value]

x: func [v] [
    if all [p a p b p c] [set-face v false]
]

view [
    title "SELECT ANY TWO"
    a: check "FAST" on-action [x a]
    b: check "CHEAP" on-action [x b]
    c: check "GOOD" on-action [x c]
]
```

This is the Rebol 3 View dialect (r3-gui).  Screendump below from Ubuntu Linux:

[image: example of rebol 3 view]

**Update** - Thanks to Earl & Graham from Rebol SO Chatroom for shaving 22 chars of the code - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16345039#16345039

Comment: It is invalid answer, as third is disabled but also checked, that means all 3 are checked, so please fix it.

Comment: @ST3 - You are incorrect I'm afraid.  The "GOOD" checkbox isn't checked or in fact disabled (my code simply flicks the third box checked OFF).  This is how Rebol 3 view shows an unchecked box (by default).

Comment: @ST3 et al - Here is a link showing default checkbox look I've described above (1st image shows no checkboxes clicked, 2nd just "GOOD") - https://plus.google.com/u/0/104216037702741908932/posts/Z2EbuQX67aq

Comment: Well... I look into print-screen you added and I see all three checkboxes checked, just only one cannot be unchecked.

Comment: @ST3 - A greyed out checkbox is just Rebol 3 View way of showing that it's a checkbox that can be checked.  The tick turns green when checked and turns back to grey when unchecked.  These are the defaults.  In the image in answer above you can see that "GOOD" as the input focus (blue blur) because its being "clicked" but it remains grey and not green (so not checked).

Answer (score 7):

## C++11/Qt5.2 - <s>561</s> <s>481</s> <s>433</s> <s>423</s> 369

Because why not.

Shockingly, as of now we are shorter than Python, and the non-buggy C#, and tied with Java!

Credits to EveBird for cutting it down from 561 to 481.

And once more EveBird shortens it from 481 to 433!

Took a few off with a lambda connect

Down to 389 with C++11 initializers

And 373 without the separate class

Removed a few spaces - 369

### Golf'd:

```c++
#include<QtWidgets>
#define C(x,y,z)z.setEnabled(x.isChecked()+y.isChecked()<2);
#define S(x)l.addWidget(&x);
#define X(x)S(x);x.connect(&x,&QCheckBox::clicked,[&](){C(g,f,c)C(g,c,f)C(f,c,g)});
int main(int n,char**v){QApplication a(n,v);QWidget m;QLabel t{"Select any two"};QCheckBox g{"Good"},f{"Fast"},c{"Cheap"};QVBoxLayout l(&m);S(t)X(g)X(f)X(c)m.show();a.exec();}
```

### Sort of Un-Golfed:

```c++
#include<QtWidgets>

#define C(x,y,z)z.setEnabled(x.isChecked()+y.isChecked()<2);
#define S(x)l.addWidget(&x);
#define X(x)S(x);connect(&x, &QCheckBox::clicked, [&](){C(g,f,c)C(g,c,f)C(f,c,g)});

int main(int n,char**v){ 
    QApplication a(n,v);
    QWidget m;
    QLabel t{"Select any two"};
    QCheckBox g{"Good"},f{"Fast"},c{"Cheap"};
    QVBoxLayout l(&m);
    S(t)X(g)X(f)X(c)m.show();
    a.exec();
}
```

[image: GFC]

Comment: +1 for the self-flagellating "why not" :)

Comment: Can improve a bit more: replace `QWidget m` with `QDialog m` and `m.show();a.exec()` with `m.exec()`.

Answer (score 6):

## CoffeeScript - <del>167</del>, 154

CoffeeScript port of **[@Matt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26785/15909)**'s answer.

```coffeescript
b="input";a="<input type=checkbox>";c=":checked";$("body").html("SELECT ANY TWO#{a}FAST#{a}GOOD#{a}CHEAP").click ->$(b).not(c).attr "disabled",!!$(b+c)[1]
```

Somewhat ungolfed:

```coffeescript
b = "input"
a = "<input type=checkbox>"
c = ":checked"

$( "body" ).html( "SELECT ANY TWO#{a}FAST#{a}GOOD#{a}CHEAP" ).click ->
    $( b ).not( c ).attr "disabled", !!$( b + c )[1]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9fQE/1/).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Rotem and Johnbot for the golfing help!

## C# <s>343</s> 334

This one uses the same "cheat" as Quincunx's [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26786/4163) - the checkboxes aren't actually disabled; they just don't allow you to check them if that check makes 3.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;using System.Linq;class P:Form{static void Main(){P p=new P();p.Text="SELECT ANY TWO";int y=0;var a=new CheckBox[3];foreach(var n in "FAST CHEAP GOOD".Split()){var c=new CheckBox();a[y]=c;c.Top=y++*50;c.Text=n;c.Validating+=(s,e)=>{if(a.Count(b=>b.Checked)>1)e.Cancel=true;};p.Controls.Add(c);}Application.Run(p);}}
```

There's also a minor bug that you can't close the window after selecting the third checkbox unless you unselect one, because the validation won't pass. But this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so who cares? ;)

## C# <s>403</s> <s>397</s> 374

This is a proper one that actually disables the third checkbox.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;using System.Linq;class P:CheckBox{static void Main(){var p=new Form{Text="SELECT ANY TWO"};P[]a=null;a="FAST CHEAP GOOD".Split().Select((x,i)=>{var c=new P{Top=i*50,Text=x};c.Click+=(s,e)=>{a.First(b=>!b.Checked).Enabled=a.Count(b=>b.Checked)>1?1<0:a.All(b=>b.Enabled=0<1);};p.Controls.Add(c);return c;}).ToArray();Application.Run(p);}}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Kinda ungolfed:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

class P:Form
{
    static void Main()
    {
        P p = new P();
        p.Text = "SELECT ANY TWO";
        int y = 0;
        var a = new CheckBox[3];
        foreach (var n in "FAST CHEAP GOOD".Split())
        {
            var c = new CheckBox(); a[y] = c; c.Top = y++ * 50; c.Text = n; c.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (a.Count(b => b.Checked) == 2)
                {
                    a.First(b => !b.Checked).Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var b in a) b.Enabled = true;
                }
            };
            p.Controls.Add(c);
        }
        Application.Run(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't `if(a.Count(b=>b.Checked)==2)e.Cancel=true;` be rewritten as `e.Cancel=a.Count(b=>b.Checked)==2;`?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, yes it could. I'm dumb. And there's a similar optimisation for the other one. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, no, there isn't for the other one. Eh, still saved some chars.

Comment: If you switch the inheritance to CheckBox, use object initializers and abuse Linq a bit you can get the proper one down to 374: `using System.Windows.Forms;using System.Linq;class P:CheckBox{static void Main(){var p=new Form{Text="SELECT ANY TWO"};P[]a=null;a="FAST CHEAP GOOD".Split().Select((x,i)=>{var c=new P{Top=i*50,Text=x};c.Click+=(s,e)=>{if(a.Count(b=>b.Checked)>1){a.First(b=>!b.Checked).Enabled=1<0;}else a.All(b=>b.Enabled=0<1);};p.Controls.Add(c);return c;}).ToArray();Application.Run(p);}}`

Comment: @Johnbot Thanks! Never would have thought of most of that. Heck, I forgot object initialisers existed!

Comment: 364 if you use the conditional operator in place of the if statement. Replace `if(a.Count(b=>b.Checked)>1){a.First(b=>!b.Ch‌​ecked).Enabled=1<0;}else a.All(b=>b.Enabled=0<1);` with `a.First(b=>!b.Checked).Enabled=a.Count(b=>b.Checked)>1?1<0:a.All(b=>b.Enabled=0<1);`

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, Javascript, jQuery - 135b

I was admiring @nderscore's answer, but then I decided to copy and one-up him.

```
<?echo"SELECT ANY TWO".($m="<input type=checkbox onclick=(a=$('input:not(:checked)')).prop('disabled',!a[1])>")."FAST$m GOOD$m CHEAP"?>
```

Basically I replaced his `.join` trick with some PHP Hypertext Preprocessing.

Comment: When you consider that 27 bytes are required for the text "resources" in the program, this is getting very close to a 100b program. Well done!

Comment: I'm not much of a PHP golfer, but I chopped a few bytes off for you: (128) `SELECT ANY TWO<?=($m="<input type=checkbox onclick=(a=$('input:not(:checked)')).prop('disabled',!a[1])>").FAST.$m.GOOD.$m.CHEAP;`

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>219</s> 218 bytes

I use the same Tk widgets as the [Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26790/4065) by Quincunx.

This program breaks the rules because it has a **check box list**. (The rules said, "Don't use a check box list.") Yes, `a` is an array of 3 TkCheckButton objects, and I believe that an array is a list. My defense is that I did not use any existing check box list, but I used the standard check boxes and made my own list.

```
require'tk'
o=->(c){c.variable.value>?0}
TkLabel.new{text'SELECT ANY TWO'
pack}
a=%w[FAST CHEAP GOOD].map{|t|TkCheckButton.new{text t
command{a.map{|c|c.state a.count(&o)<2||o[c]?:normal: :disabled}}
pack}}
Tk.mainloop
```

[image: CHEAP and GOOD checked, but FAST disabled]

I tested with Ruby 2.1.0 and Tk 8.5.15.

- `o[c]` is a predicate to test if check button `c` is selected. With the default strings, `c.variable.value` is `'0'` or `'1'`, so the string comparison is only true if `'1'>'0'`. EDIT: I saved 1 byte (219 down to 218) by changing `'0'` to `?0`. In Ruby, `?0` is a character constant.
- `a.count(&o)` uses the predicate to count the selected check buttons.
- When the user toggles a check button, the command calls `a.map` to loop for all buttons, making them `:normal` or `:disabled`.

Comment: Very good. No rule breaking here - I was referring to a check box list _control_ that may happen to be part of the language framework. I believe all of the answers so far use some kind of map or selector, so this is totally legit.

Answer (score 5):

## AngularJS - 214

```
<input type=checkbox ng-model=fast ng-disabled=cheap&&good>FAST</input>
<input type=checkbox ng-model=cheap ng-disabled=fast&&good>CHEAP</input>
<input type=checkbox ng-model=good ng-disabled=fast&&cheap>GOOD</input>
```

Comment: I tried this out at JSFiddle, but [without any success](http://jsfiddle.net/rLEQU/). Can you provide a working example?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1FQOQyGJXlC9r3Rk2Zr?p=preview

Comment: You did not mention "ng-app". Check <head> in my example.

Comment: Ah, OK :-)  You can [golf it down a bit](http://jsfiddle.net/rLEQU/1/) by removing the quotation marks and extra line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

**Mathematica**

A more code-golfed version as suggested by David, **255 characters**:

```
h = Checkbox;
i = Dynamic;
j = Enabled;
t = True;
i[
 If[Total@Boole@{a, b, c} == 2,
  {d, e, f} = {a, b, c},
  {d, e, f} = {t, t, t}
  ];
 Row@{
   "SELECT ANY TWO",
   h[i@a, j -> d], "FAST",
   h[i@b, j -> e], "CHEAP",
   h[i@c, j -> f], "GOOD"
   }
 ]
```

Comment: You can save some characters by using `h=Checkbox;i=Dynamic;j=Enabled`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Thanks, I can see myself using that technique for other code golfing question in the future as well.

Comment: No need to include both versions. And don't forget to use `h` and to adjust your char count in the heading.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (with jQuery) - <strike>224</strike>, <strike>222</strike>, <strike>210</strike>, <strike>205</strike>, 178

```
a="<input type=checkbox>",c=":checked",e="input",f="disabled",d=$("body").html("SELECT ANY TWO"+a+" FAST"+a+"CHEAP"+a+"GOOD").click(function(){$(e).not(c).attr(f,$(e+c).length>1)})
```

Thanks to a comment from brilliant @Matt I reduced the code by 27 characters.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9vGn/4/)**

Comment: Save 25 or so by moving your condition `$(e+c).length>1` into the assignment as such: `$(e).not(c).attr(f,$(e+c).length>1)` since you're only changing the boolean itself.

Comment: Managed to get it down to 169 using a mix of yours and mine. The `!!` coercion and a little extra golfing with not assigning body to d. `a="<input type=checkbox>",c=":checked",e="input";$("body").html("SELECT ANY TWO"+a+"FAST"+a+"CHEAP"+a+"GOOD").click(function(){$(e).not(c).attr("disabled",!!$(e+c)[1])})`

Answer (score 4):

## k3 - 95

```
a[`FAST`CHEAP`GOOD]:0
a[.;`c]:`check
a..l:"SELECT ANY TWO"
a..t:"if[3=+/a[];.[_v;_i;:;0]]"
`show$`a
```

[code is here](http://nsl.com/k/anytwo.k)

[image: sample run]
<sub>(source: [nsl.com](http://nsl.com/k/anytwo.jpg))</sub>

Comment: line 1: a dictionary with three variables; line 2: each variable is a checkbutton; line 3: label the dictionary; line 4: if three variables have been checked, reset the last variable checked to 0; line 5: show the dictionary.

Comment: Nice! Such a tragedy k4 has no GUI...

Comment: k wins (but oh irony! 9 more characters are required in order to post!)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>335</strike> <strike>333</strike> <strike>326</strike> <strike>320</strike> 308

Based off Bobs Answer, mine does use fewer characters than his (335 v 342), but I might not understand fully how to count this.

```c#
using System.Linq;using System.Windows.Forms;class P:Form{static void Main(){new P();}P(){Text="SELECT ANY TWO";var a="FAST CHEAP GOOD".Split().Select(r=>new CheckBox{Text=r,Top=r[0]%9*20}).ToList();a.All(r=>{r.Validating+=(b,c)=>c.Cancel=a.Count(z=>z.Checked)>1;Controls.Add(r);return 1>0;});ShowDialog();}}
```

Ungolfed

```c#
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class P : Form
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new P();
    }

    P()
    {
        Text = "SELECT ANY TWO";

        var a = "FAST CHEAP GOOD".Split().Select(r => new CheckBox
        {
            Text = r,
            Top = r[0] % 9 * 20
        }).ToList();

        //loops, I dont need no stinking loops
        a.All(r => { r.Validating += (b, c) => c.Cancel = a.Count(z => z.Checked) > 1; Controls.Add(r); return 1 > 0; });
        ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great use of anon functions and Linq here, especially like the `Select`.

Comment: You can save a couple more characters by replacing the `==2` with a `>1`, and the `true` with a `1>0`. You can also use a `All` instead of `Where` and `Last`. `ToList` is also shorter than `ToArray`.

Comment: @Bob Good call, don't know how I missed All(), and as a bonus, turns out with All you don't have to materialize it, saving even more

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy - <strike>357</strike> <strike>221</strike> 217 chars

I've ported [Quincunx's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26786/21004) to Groovy 2.2.1, using [SwingBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder) (and made it even more Groovier):

```
c=[];new groovy.swing.SwingBuilder().frame(){panel(){label("SELECT ANY TWO");f={if(c.count{it.isSelected()}>2)it.source.setSelected(1<0)};["FAST","CHEAP","GOOD"].each{c<<checkBox(label:it,itemStateChanged:f)}}}.show()
```

Ungolfed:

```
c=[]
new groovy.swing.SwingBuilder().frame() {
    panel() {
        label("SELECT ANY TWO")
        f = { if (c.count{it.isSelected()} > 2) it.source.setSelected(1<0) }
        ["FAST","CHEAP","GOOD"].each { c << checkBox(label: it, itemStateChanged: f) }
    }
}.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

## mIRC script (<strike>727</strike> 719 bytes)

Forgot about this language until a drunken conversation last night.

```
alias select_two {
  dialog -m s2 s2
}

dialog s2 {
  title "Select any two:"
  size -1 -1 200 100
  check "Fast",1, 5 10 170 25
  check "Cheap",2, 5 30 170 25
  check "Good",3, 5 50 170 25 
}

on *:dialog:s2:sclick:*: {
  if ($did(s2, $did).state = 1) {
    if ($did = 1) {
      if ($did(s2, 2).state = 1) { did -b s2 3 }
      if ($did(s2, 3).state = 1) { did -b s2 2 }
    }
    if ($did = 2) {
      if ($did(s2, 1).state = 1) { did -b s2 3 }
      if ($did(s2, 3).state = 1) { did -b s2 1 }
    }
    if ($did = 3) {
      if ($did(s2, 1).state = 1) { did -b s2 2 }
      if ($did(s2, 2).state = 1) { did -b s2 1 }
    }
  }
  if ($did(s2, $did).state = 0) {
    did -e s2 1
    did -e s2 2
    did -e s2 3
  }
}
```

More should be coded in this language! But there needs to be a way to make this into a real mess so it can be as good as Perl.

Edit: noticed that my Python-isms are leaking through and was able to reduce the code by 8 bytes!

Comment: Haha, I like the intro to this one. It's kind of verbose though - could it be the beer speaking? =c)

Answer (score 3):

### QML - <strike>369</strike> <strike>315</strike> <strike>254</strike> <strike>251</strike> 248 bytes

Here goes QML (QtQuick 2.0) version, given only the .qml file contents. This code requires Qt 5.1 at least to run. Not a big deal as its huge compared to other solutions (**248 bytes**), but it's a full featured cross-platform application (Android and iOs included)! :D

```
    import QtQuick 2.0;import QtQuick.Controls 1.1;Row{Text{text:"SELECT ANY TWO"}CheckBox{id:a;text:"FAST";enabled:!b.checked|!c.checked}CheckBox{id:b;text:"CHEAP";enabled:!a.checked|!c.checked}CheckBox{id:c;text:"GOOD";enabled:!b.checked|!a.checked}}
```

[image: Horizontal layout dialog]

To run it, save the code to a .qml file, install Qt 5.1 and run qmlscene.exe (or just qmlscene on linux), which will show an open file dialog. Chose the .qml file you've saved the code to and see the awesome result! :D

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript 209 (was 346)

Shortened: thanks for comments.

```
function f(){var a=document.getElementsByClassName("x"),n=0,i=0;for(i in a){if(a[i].checked)n++;}if(n<2){for(i in a){a[i].disabled=false;}}else{for(i in a){i(false===a[i].checked){a[i].disabled=true;break;}}}}
```

Golfed function:

```
function f(a,b,c){
var x=document.getElementById(a);
var y=document.getElementById(b);
var z=document.getElementById(c);
var n=0,i=0;
var a=[x,y,z];
for(i in a)
{
if(a[i].checked) n++;
}
if(n<2)
{
for(i in a)
{
a[i].disabled=false;
}
}
else
{
for(i in a)
{
if(false===a[i].checked)
{
a[i].disabled=true;
break;
}
}
}
}
```

HTML form: provides input and calls the function.
* Form now uses class=x to group inputs.

```
<form>
        SELECT ANY TWO<br>
        FAST <input id="a" type="checkbox" class="x" value="0" onchange="f()"><br>
        CHEAP <input id="b" type="checkbox" class="x" value="1" onchange="f()"><br>
        GOOD <input id="c" type="checkbox" class="x" value="2" onchange="f()"><br>
    </form>
```

Tested with NetBeans and Chrome.

Comment: You can golf the function further and reduce it to 264 characters by consolidating all of your `var`s, removing unnecessary braces and whitespace (including newline chars). You could probably get it smaller if you use an ES6 lambda.

Comment: Apart from some more obvious golfing, consider using a class to pull all of the input elements into an array in one hit instead, using `getElementsByClassName` eg. `a=document.getElementsByClassName('q')`.

Comment: change the ids to name and just call them with `document.a`, `document.c`, `document.c` also put them directly into a[]

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript / jQuery <strike>237 234</strike> 229

Very similar approach as [Matt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26785/6520), although a little longer.

```
$(function(){var e="input ",t="disabled",n,r;$("body").html("SELECT ANY TWO|FAST|CHEAP|GOOD".replace(/\|/g,"<"+e+'type="checkbox">'));n=$(e);n.change(function(){n.removeAttr(t);r=$(":checked");if(r.length>1)n.not(r).attr(t,t)})})
```

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy

Based on the Java version, but much slimmed down ;)

Types were replaced by 'def', semicolons removed, add replaced by <<, the 1<0 replaced by 0, collect for creating the checkboxes, removed the itemevent type, removed casting the checkbox, enhanced the loops.

```
import java.awt.*
class F {
    def static main(a) {
        def f = new Frame()
        def p = new Panel()
        f << p
        p << new Label("SELECT ANY TWO")
        def c = ['FAST','CHECK','GOOD'].collect { new Checkbox(it) }
        c.each { b ->
            p << b
            b.addItemListener { e->
                int x = 0, i = 0
                3.times {
                    x += c[it].state ? 1 : 0
                }
                if (x > 2) {
                    e.source.state = 0                        
                }
            }
        }
        f.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Groovy is not java. That means that all those enhancements don't count as much. Everything you removed was necessary in java, but not groovy.

Comment: You're right, Groovy is not Java, that why it's called Groovy. I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.

Answer (score 1):

## TCL 347

At least it beats Python and Java.

```
set d .
proc a v {upvar f f c c g g d d $v x
if $x&&$f+$c+$g==2 {set d .$f$c$g
$d configure -state disabled} 
if !$x {$d configure -state normal}}
set z -variable
set y -command
set x checkbutton
label .l -text {SELECT ANY TWO}
$x .011 -text FAST $z f $y a\ f
$x .101 -text CHEAP $z c $y a\ c
$x .110 -text GOOD $z g $y a\ g
pack .l .011 .101 .110
```

Note: if you start by selecting one checkbox and immediately unselecting it, you will get an error. You can fix it by adding `110` to the end of the first line.

Ungolfed:

```
# Keep track of the last disabled button. Set it to something valid to start with.
set last .110

proc toggled name {
        # Access some globals
        upvar fast  fast
        upvar cheap cheap
        upvar good  good
        upvar last  last
        upvar $name value

        # Just toggled one on, check if exactly two are now on
        if {$value == 1 && ($fast + $cheap + $good) == 2} {
                set last .$fast$cheap$good
                $last configure -state disabled
        }
        # Just toggled one off. Re-enable disabled one.
        if {$value == 0} {
                $last configure -state normal
        }
}

label .label -text {SELECT ANY TWO}

checkbutton .011 -text FAST  -variable fast  -command {toggled fast}
checkbutton .101 -text CHEAP -variable cheap -command {toggled cheap}
checkbutton .110 -text GOOD  -variable good  -command {toggled good}

pack .label .011 .101 .110
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript + Knockout: ~250 Characters

```
a=function(i){return "<input type=checkbox data-bind='value: "+i+", checked: x, disable: x().length>=2 && x().indexOf(\""+i+"\")==-1'>"},document.body.innerHTML = "SELECT ANY TWO"+a(0)+"Fast"+a(1)+"Good"+a(2)+"Cheap"; ko.applyBindings({x:ko.observableArray([])})
```

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/p5dNF/)

Answer (score 0):

## AngularJS - 155 ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/at4kz/))

```html
SELECT ANY TWO :<i ng-init=t=[]><p ng-repeat="(i,v) in ['FAST','CHEAP','GOOD']"><input type=checkbox ng-disabled=t[(i+1)%3]&&t[(i+2)%3] ng-model=t[i]>{{v}}
```

The ungolfed version:

```html
SELECT ANY TWO :
<i ng-init="checkedArray = []" /> <!-- A useless tag to initialize the array (which can't be done on the `input` tag, unfortunately) -->
<p ng-repeat="(key, value) in ['FAST', 'CHEAP', 'GOOD']">
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        ng-model="checkedArray[key]"
        ng-disabled="checkedArray[(key + 1) % 3] && checkedArray[(key + 2) % 3]"
    />
    {{value}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby with Shoes, 133 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app{para'SELECT ANY TWO'
$o=%w{FAST GOOD CHEAP}.map{|q|c=check{|c|$o[c]=!$o[c];$o.values.all?&&c.checked=p}
para q
[c,p]}.to_h}
```

Sample output:

[image: Shoes window screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## FLTK, 303 characters

```fluid
decl{int c;}Function{}{}{Fl_Window{}{xywh {9 9 195 195}}{Fl_Pack{}{label{SELECT ANY TWO}}{Fl_Check_Button{}{callback{e(o);}label FAST}Fl_Check_Button{}{callback{e(o);}label GOOD}Fl_Check_Button{}{callback{e(o);}label CHEAP}}}}Function{e(Fl_Button*o)}{}{code{if((c+=o->value()*2-1)>2){o->value(0);c--;}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```fluid
decl { int c; }

Function {} {} {
    Fl_Window {} {
        xywh {9 9 195 195}
    } {
        Fl_Pack {} {
            label {SELECT ANY TWO}
        } {
            Fl_Check_Button {} {
                callback { e(o); }
                label FAST
            }
            Fl_Check_Button {} {
                callback { e(o); }
                label GOOD
            }
            Fl_Check_Button {} {
                callback { e(o); }
                label CHEAP
            }
        }
    }
}

Function { e(Fl_Button* o) } {} {
    code {
        if ((c += o->value() * 2 - 1) > 2) {
            o->value(0);
            c--;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image: FLTK window screenshot]