# How do I alias member functions in Python?

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

In Python, one can save bytes by aliasing functions that are used repeatedly. For example:

```
r=range
a=r(100)
b=r(200)
c=r(300)
```

However, when the functions are member functions together, I don't know how to alias them in a way that allows chaining. For example:

```
s='Hello'

// Plain code
s=s.replace('H','J').replace('e','i').replace('l','m').replace('o','y')

// What I am trying to do
q=replace
s=s.q('H','J').q('e','i').q('l','m').q('o','y')
```

Obviously, what I am trying to do is not valid. And neither is this:

```
q=s.replace
s=q('H','J') // Replaces the 'H' in 'Hello'
s=q('e','i') // Replaces the 'e' in 'Hello'... and the J is gone.
s=q('l','m')
s=q('o','y')
```

Is there a another way to alias member functions and chained functions that saves characters?

Comment: Define your own class, with its method `q` meaning what `replace` means in the class your using.

Comment: @Ypnypn I see. So you alias the *class* rather than the *function*. It seems obvious now that you said it. Do you want to post your answer? I'll even expand it with an example when I get around to it, but I don't get any rep for answering my own question.

Comment: I'm glad this hasn't been downvoted :)

Comment: I have literally no idea why this kind of tips question has to CW, too.

Comment: I've unwikied all the answers for now, but we haven't reached a strong enough consensus to call for unwiki-ing this and similar questions. See also: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1555/3808

Comment: Now that the aforementioned meta discussion is semi-official (or at least most of us agree), I've gone ahead and removed the wiki on this post.

Comment: Your last version doesn't work. `q` is bound to the replace method of that specific `str` instance. Also, remember you can do single char replacements with `"Hello".replace(*"HJ")`

Comment: @gnibbler Wow, you're right. I guess I never actually tested the bad version. I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**No problemo!** You can alias a method, but you have to know how to use it:

```
>>> r=str.replace
>>> a='hello'
>>> r(r(r(r(a,'h','j'),'e','i'),'l','m'),'o','y')
'jimmy'
```

The key is that you have to pass `self` explicitly, because the alias is a kind of function that takes an extra argument that takes `self`:

```
>>> type(r)
<type 'method_descriptor'>
```

Comment: How did I not see this before?

Answer (score 6):

Define your own class, with a shorter method name.

For example, if you're using the method `replace()` belonging to the `String` class, you could make your own class `S` have a method called `q` which does the same thing.

Here is one implementation:

```
class m(str):
 def q(a,b,c):return m(a.replace(b,c))
```

Here is a much better implementation:

```
class m(str):q=lambda a,b,c:m(a.replace(b,c))
```

Use it like so:

```
s="Hello"
s=m(s).q('H','J').q('e','i').q('l','m').q('o','y')
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a few characters shorter anyway

```
j=iter('HJeilmoy')
for i in j:s=s.replace(i,next(j))
```

even shorter for a small number of replacements is

```
for i in['HJ','ei','lm','oy']:s=s.replace(*i)
```

of course this just covers one particular case. However code golf is all about finding those special cases that can save you bytes.

It's possible to write a wrapper function that handles the general case, but the code will be too large to have a place in most code golf challenges.

You instead need to think "I can do this transformation efficiently (strokewise) with str.replace. Can I shift the internal representation of my solution to take advantage of that? (without wasting so many strokes to negate the advantage)"

Comment: I do like this answer because it describes good habits when golfing and definitely solves the specific example presented. I accepted another answer because it is applicable to the more general case.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `reduce` function.

```python
reduce(lambda s,(a,b):s.replace(a,b),[('H','J'),('e','i'),('l','m'),('o','y')],'Hello')
```

Comment: If your answer different from [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26844/18487) answer (as far as technique used, not necessarily written in the *exact* same form)?

Comment: @Rusher It is different. E.g. the number of invocations is hard-coded in the linked answer while here it is given only by the length of the second argument (which can be any iterator).

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing a *lot* of replaces, you could do this:

```
s=''.join({'H':'J','e':'i','l':'m','o':'y'}[a] for a in list(s))
```

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that wasn't specific to replace. I just used that as an example.

Comment: This can only replace 1 char at a time, but it can insert multi-char replacements. And this is not fully golfed (remove the space after `[a]`)

Comment: Doesn't the `[a]` have to be replaced with `.get(a,a)` (otherwise, we get some Key Error thing)? And why have `list(s)` instead of `s`?

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a lambda function?

```
r=lambda s,a,b:s.replace(a,b)

s=r(r(r(r(s,'H','J'),'e','i'),'l','m'),'o','y')
```

Comment: No need: `str.replace` /is/ that lambda! See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your replacements don't need to be chained, you can use `str.translate'. The numbers are the ASCII ordinals. Using it this way requires Python 3:

```python
print("Hello".translate({72:74,101:105,108:109,111:121}))
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/3mXbsY)