# Make me a mooncake!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The [mid-autumn festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Autumn_Festival) has begun!

Unfortunately, all my mooncakes were stolen -- they're getting too expensive for small folk such as myself, and I fear I won't be able to eat any this year!

So I turn to you for help. Would you be able to make me some?

For those unaware, let me educate you on what a mooncake looks like.

---

Mooncakes come in many different sizes!
So I'm gonna give you my **input**, *n*, when I want one.

Here are some examples of the **output** I want:

Mooncake of size n = 3:

```
    (@@@@@)  
    (@MAF@) 
    (@@@@@)
```

Mooncake of size n = 6:

```
    (@@@@@@@@@@@) 
    (@         @)
    (@    M    @) 
    (@    F    @)
    (@         @)
    (@@@@@@@@@@@)
```

That is to say, a mooncake of size *n* is:

- *n* lines high
- *2n - 1* @s long
- *2n + 1* characters long (@s and brackets)

And you better not throw me your too-tiny practice mooncakes!
**Assume input will always be n >= 3**.

Mooncakes also **contain one of the following decorations**:

- MF
- MAF
- HMF
- JCJ
- TTT
- ZJ
- LF
- RF
- CF

Which one, it doesn't matter - as long as it is **vertically and horizontally centered**.
It can be written vertically or horizontally too!

I want variety!
If you're really going to make me two of the same mooncake, the decoration better be different!

That is, **multiple executions of your program with the exact same input must not always yield the same decoration**.

I can't wait to eat your moon cakes, so the sooner I can receive them (**the shorter your code**) the better!

Good Luck!

---

For those wondering about the decorations:
They are the initials of all alternative names for the Mid-Autumn Festival.
A list can be found in the Wikipedia page linked at the top of this post.

---

**Clarifications:**

*There are no rules regarding leading and trailing whitespace*.
Have as much or as little as you like!

*The decorations must be in the very center of your mooncake!*
On horizontal decorations, this means it must be on the middle line of your cake, and the number of characters to the left and right of the decoration string must be equal.
On vertical decorations, this means it must reside in the middle column of your cake, and the number of characters above and below the decoration must be equal.

***Not all decorations must be used!***
The only requirement is that there must be more than one possibility for any given input *n*. The possibilities also do not need to be even.

*Functions are acceptable.*

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! This looks like a great first post. usually we recommend to use the [Sandbox for proposed challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). There you can get feedback from others, and perfect the challenge with things you might have not thought about, before posting it here. That being said, your challenge looks well-thought-out. +1 from me. One question regarding your first example though, why does it read `MAF` and not `MF`? I don't see an `A` in your decoration-options.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I wasn't aware of the sandbox. Am I able to leave just this one up anyway? About the decoration - that was a mistake. I added MAF to the allowed decorations. Feedback very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, of course it can stay. The Sandbox isn't mandatory. It's just to perfect a challenge and get feedback from multiple other people, before posting it here. I personally always use it, because you might get questions with things you might not have thought about. So you don't have to use the Sandbox, but I can recommend it for future challenges. :)

Comment: Are the leading spaces required? Is variation there allowed?

Comment: There are no rules regarding leading and trailing spaces. Up to you!

Comment: Can we get a bonus for having all decorations in all possible directions?

Comment: [We shouldn't](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8512/55696) get a bonus.  Bonuses are bad.

Comment: @StevenH. They can be bad and pointless: you need to compute whether the bonus will be appropriate or still bigger than no bonus at all (i.e. writing a 30-byte code for a -10% bonus is bad when you can do it in 20 instead of 27). Also, most answers will try to accomplish the bonus, no matter what. It's like "duping in the same post".

Comment: Is a function okay, or must it be runnable (`main` etc) as-is?

Comment: I don't think I will add a bonus for including extra decorations (at this point). Thank you for the suggestion though! Also, I will clarify in the main post shortly - functions are acceptable.

Comment: "so the sooner I can receive them (the shorter your code) the better!" You do realize that golfed code will make you receive them *later*, right?

Comment: Hey, I need to manually type all this into my mooncake machine to get the actual mooncakes!

Comment: ... in which case it's good that none of those contrived languages with non-ASCII character sets have reared their head, because they are a pain to type :)

Comment: lol, +1. High-end mooncake brands like Wing Wah (http://www.mooncake.com/) routinely run close to US$50 for a box of four.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <s>71</s> <s>65</s> <s>59</s> 58 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @StevenH.*

```
jjRc"(@@)"2++J*KtytQ\@m.[Kd;.[ttQ@,,O"MC"\F]Oc"MAFHMF"3QkJ
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjRc%22(%40%40)%222%2B%2BJ*KtytQ%5C%40m.%5BKd%3B.%5BttQ%40%2C%2CO%22MC%22%5CF%5DOc%22MAFHMF%223QkJ&input=4&test_suite_input=3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjRc%22(%40%40)%222%2B%2BJ*KtytQ%5C%40m.%5BKd%3B.%5BttQ%40%2C%2CO%22MC%22%5CF%5DOc%22MAFHMF%223QkJ&input=4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0)

So much padding.

Comment: It's nuts how different this answer is from the one below it in the same language...

Comment: You can save one byte by replacing `?%Q2` with `@,` (reverse the order of the two choices)...`Q`.  I (ab)used that a lot in golfing my own Pyth answer down.

Comment: @StevenH. Thanks, I always forget about modular indexing.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>206</s> <s>196</s> <s>192</s> <s>188</s> <s>187</s> <s>180</s> <s>176</s> <s>169</s> <s>165</s> 156 bytes

```
g=(n,r=new Date%2,a=(s,x,b=' @'[+!s].repeat(n-3+!x))=>`(@${b+(s||'@')+b}@)
`,l=a` `.repeat(n/2-2+n%2))=>a()+l+(n%2?a(r?'MAF':'HMF',1):a('RC'[r])+a`F`)+l+a()
```

#### Breakdown

```
r=new Date%2                           // Sometimes 0, sometimes 1

// Function to create lines of the cake of the form `(@@@@@@@@@)` or `(@  ${s}  @)`
a=(s,x,b=' @'[+!s].repeat(n-3+!x))=>`(@${b+(s||'@')+b}@)
`

// Cake parts
a()                                    // Top of the cake.
l=a` `.repeat(n/2-2+n%2)               // Undecorated inner part.
a(r?'MAF':'HMF',1)                     // Decoration for uneven sized cakes.
a('RC'[r])+a`F`                        // Decoration for even sized cakes.
l                                      // Undecorated inner part.
a()                                    // Bottom part.
```

My first attempt at code-golf. This can probably be golfed more.

*saved 4 bytes thanks to @ETHProductions*

**Edit**
I took the liberty of using <s>`Date.now()%2`</s> `new Date%2` to satisfy:

> multiple executions of your program with the exact same input must not always yield the same decoration

this allows me to save another 7 bytes over `+Math.random()>.5`

*saved another 4 bytes thanks to @Arnauld*

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and great first answer! I believe `['MA','HA'][r]+'F'` can be golfed to `'MH'[r]+'AF'`.

Comment: It could, thank you. However, it actually should have been `['MA','HM'][r] + 'F'` in the first place, because the solution won't fulfil the spec otherwise. So thank you for making me aware of that typo :)

Comment: You can save two bytes by replacing `[' R ',' C '][r]` with `" ${'RC'[r]} "`, replacing each `"` with a backtick.

Comment: And `['MA','HM'][r]+'F'` is actually two bytes longer than `['MAF','HMF'][r]` ;)

Comment: Nothing serious, but the `+l+a()` is missing in your breakdown. ;) I like the idea of painting it all at once.

Comment: You can use `' @'[+!s]` instead of `(s?' ':'@')`

Comment: Also, you can use `new Date%2` instead of `Date.now()%2`.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>99</s> <s>79</s> <s>71</s> <s>68</s> 64 bytes

Pyth is <s>very bad</s> all right at making strings.  Or maybe I'm just <s>bad</s> getting better at golfing them.

```
jmj.[-yQ3@,k@,@,O"MC"\FgydQOc"MAFHMF"3Q>2ahydQ@" @"sIcdtQc2"(@@)
```

Can create the decorations `MAF` and `HMF` horizontally, and the decorations `MF` and `CF` vertically.

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jmj.%5B-yQ3%40%2Ck%40%2C%40%2CO%22MC%22%5CFgydQOc%22MAFHMF%223Q%3E2ahydQ%40%22+%40%22sIcdtQc2%22%28%40%40%29&input=6&debug=0)

Comment: Ahh, good to see some character development in this story.

Answer (score 6):

## Vim, 118 bytes

Takes input as a buffer (e.g. a file with the number *n* as its contents).

```
"aDi()<Esc>@ai@<Esc>.xY@apddll<C-v>G$k3hr @=@a/2-1
j@=@a-2-@a%2
l:let r=abs(reltime()[1])%2
@=@a%2?r?"RJCJ":"3rT":"rFkr"."ML"[r]
<Esc>
```

Here it is with the unprintable control characters in xxd format:

```
0000000: 2261 4469 2829 1b40 6169 401b 2e78 5940  "aDi().@ai@..xY@
0000010: 6170 6464 6c6c 1647 246b 3368 7220 403d  apddll.G$k3hr @=
0000020: 4061 2f32 2d31 0a6a 403d 4061 2d32 2d40  @a/2-1.j@=@a-2-@
0000030: 6125 320a 6c3a 6c65 7420 723d 6162 7328  a%2.l:let r=abs(
0000040: 7265 6c74 696d 6528 295b 315d 2925 320a  reltime()[1])%2.
0000050: 403d 4061 2532 3f72 3f22 524a 434a 223a  @=@a%2?r?"RJCJ":
0000060: 2233 7254 223a 2272 466b 7222 2e22 4d4c  "3rT":"rFkr"."ML
0000070: 225b 725d 0a1b                           "[r]..
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=ImFEaSgpG0BhaUAbLnhZQGFwZGRsbBZHJGszaHIgQD1AYS8yLTEKakA9QGEtMi1AYSUyCmw6bGV0IHI9YWJzKHJlbHRpbWUoKVsxXSklMgpAPUBhJTI_cj8iUkpDSiI6IjNyVCI6InJGa3IiLiJNTCJbcl0KGw&input=&args=OQ) (As it turns out, the V interpreter works fine for normal Vim code, too.)

## Explanation

```
"aD                   " Delete the number and store it in @a
i()<Esc>              " Insert empty parentheses
@ai@<Esc>.x           " Insert @a '@' characters between the parentheses twice; delete 1
Y@apdd                " Copy the line and paste it @a times; delete 1
ll<C-v>G$k3hr<Space>  " Replace the inner area with spaces
@=@a/2-1<CR>j         " Go down @a/2-1 lines
@=@a-2-@a%2<CR>l      " Go right @a-2-@a%2 columns
:let r=reltime()[1]%2<CR>  " Get a random 1 or 0 based on the time (this may be OS-dependent)
@=@a%2?
   r?"RJCJ":"3rT"     " For odd @a, replace the next 3 characters with "JCJ" or "TTT"
  :"rFkr"."ML"[r]     " For even @a, replace this character with "F" and the above with "M" or "L"
<CR><Esc>
```

Comment: Wow, nice! I think this is the first non-deterministic vim answer I've seen! A couple thoughts: 1) When you put the input in "arguments" rather than "input", it predefines `@a` to arg1, `@b` to arg2, etc. but this is a V specific feature. This doesn't technically matter since you have `"aD` at the beginning, but I just thought I'd point it out. 2) You could take one byte off if you did `dd@ap` instead of `Y@apdd`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem `dd@ap` [doesn't quite work](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=ImFEaSgpG0BhaUAbLnhkZEBhcGxsFkckazNociBAPUBhLzItMQpqQD1AYS0yLUBhJTIKbDpsZXQgcj1hYnMocmVsdGltZSgpWzFdKSUyCkA9QGElMj9yPyJSSkNKIjoiM3JUIjoickZrciIuIk1MIltyXQob&input=&args=OQ) alas.

Comment: `dd@aP` works, but then requires an additional `j` and an additional `k` down the line.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>342</s> <s>292</s> <s>249</s> <s>185</s> <s>178</s> 176 bytes

```
for(;$i<$n=$argv[1];)$o.=str_pad("(@",2*$n-1," @"[$i++%($n-1)<1])."@)
";$p=F.[M,AM,R,MH][rand()&2|$d=$n&1];$f=$n*($n+$d)-2;for($i=2+$d;$i--;$f+=$d?:2*$n+2)$o[$f]=$p[$i];echo$o;
```

Call with `php -r '<code>' <size>`

**history**

Rev 1: initial version; all sizes (including tiny cakes), all decorations, all possible directions

Rev. 2: removed tiny cakes (-36 bytes), restructured decoration options, removed one decoration item (-21) and a single byte golf (-1).

Rev. 3: Down to four decorations; (-17), only horizontal for odd sizes (-18) plus minor golfing (-8).

Rev. 4: Thanks to Jörg for golfing down the "paint cake" part; he took off an amazing (-31).
Another -6 with my additional golfing, and -27 for using a single string instead of an array of strings.

Rev. 5: -7 bytes mostly thanks to Christallkeks

**breakdown**

This is getting slimmer by the hour. :)

```
// paint cake
for(;$i<$n=$argv[1];)$o.=str_pad("(@",2*$n-1," @"[$i++%($n-1)<1])."@)\n";

// add deco
$p=F.[M,AM,R,MH][rand()&2|$d=$n&1];
$f=$n*($n+$d)-2;
for($i=2+$d;$i--;$f+=$d?:2*$n+2)$o[$f]=$p[$i];

// output
echo$o;
```

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<$n=$argv[1];$i++){$o[]=str_pad("(@",2*$n-1,!$i|$i==$n-1?"@":" ")."@)";} `

Comment: @JörgHülsermann: Lots of thanks. I had to take a similar expression for `!$i|$‌​i==$n-1?"@":" "`; the ternary would just not accept yours (on my machine), although it is correct.

Comment: try it for example on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: This saves you six bytes on the cake paint: `for(;$i<$n=$argv[1];)$o.=str_pad("(@",2*$n-1," @"[$i++%($n-1)==0])."@)\n";` Also, it looks like you got "MAD" golfing your decos ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 7, <s>399</s> 349 bytes

Updated version with help from @Dodge and @Kevin Cruijssen:

```java
void m(int n){int i=2,r=n%2,x=2*n,u=r+2,y=r*4+(int)(Math.random()*2)*u,z=y+u;String t="MFZJMAFHMF".substring(y,z);char[][]c=new char[n][x+1];while(i<x-1)c[0][i]=c[n-1][i++]=64;for(i=0;i<u;)c[(n-1)/2+(1-r)*i][r*(i-1)+n]=t.charAt(i++);for(i=0;i<n;){c[i][0]=40;c[i][1]=c[i][x-1]=64;c[i][x]=41;System.out.println(new String(c[i++]).replace('\0',' '));}}
```

```
void m(int n){String[]s={"MF","MAF","ZJ","HMF","LF","JCJ","RF","TTT","CF","MAF"};char[]d=s[((int)(Math.random()*5))*2+(n%2)].toCharArray(),c[]=new char[n][2*n+1];int i=2;while(i<2*n-1)c[0][i]=c[n-1][i++]='@';i=0;while(i<d.length)c[(n-1)/2+(1-(n%2))*i][(n%2)*(-1+i)+n]=d[i++];i=0;while(i<n){c[i][0]='(';c[i][1]=c[i][2*n-1]='@';c[i][2*n]=')';System.out.println(new String(c[i++]).replace('\0',' '));}}
```

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/yQ1fgg)

The new version is much more optimized and got rid of the `String` array handling. Also as suggested, there are only 4 decorations now: 2 for even inputs (`MF`,`ZJ`) and 2 for odd inputs (`MAF`,`HMF`) which are combined into a single `String`.

**Ungolfed:**

```java
void m(int n){
    int i=2,
    r=n%2,
    x=2*n,
    u=r+2, // length of the decoration string
    y=r*4+(int)(Math.random()*2)*u, // random starting index of string (0, 2, 4, 7)
    z=y+u; // exclusive end index of string (2, 4, 7, 10)
    String t="MFZJMAFHMF".substring(y,z);
    char[][]c=new char[n][x+1];
    while(i < x-1) {
        c[0][i]=c[n-1][i++]=64; // '@'
    }
    for(i=0; i<u;) {
        c[(n-1)/2+(1-r)*i][r*(i-1)+n]=t.charAt(i++); // Depending on even/odd, fills the center column/row respectively with the decoration
    }
    for(i=0; i<n;) {
        c[i][0]=40; // '('
        c[i][1]=c[i][x-1]=64; // '@'
        c[i][x]=41; // ')'
        System.out.println(new String(c[i++]).replace('\0',' ')); // Print all
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the submission! Let me clarify, as a few users have missed it - not all decorations must be included. I have gone ahead and bolded this in the 'clarifications' section. Hopefully that will save you a few bytes! I believe you would still be able to use the same method to select decorations.

Comment: Haha, as far as Java golfing goes, he might as well include all of the decorations ;). +1, always, for anyone with the balls to whip out the Java-putter.

Comment: Why is `"MAF"` repeated?

Comment: @carusocomputing Very true. Just in case, though, I thought I'd mention it. Nice!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)  True, Java isn't very optimal for golfing, but it's pretty fun to do it :P. Maybe I could use the loops and initialization of the decoration `char[]` more efficiently and golf other things further. @Cyoce I duplicated `MAF` because then I have all decorations for an even input at indices `0,2,4,6,8` and all decorations for an odd input at indices `1,3,5,7,9`. That makes it easier to calculate the random index for a given input. `Math.random()*5` gives a random number from `0-4`. `*2` spreads it to `0,2,4,6,8`. `+n%2` adds `1` for odd inputs to get `1,3,5,7,9`.

Comment: @QBrute can't you just do `((int)(Math.random()*10))` instead of  `((int)(Math.random()*5))*2` would save 1 byte :D

Comment: @QBrute actually you can remove the outer parenteses to save another 2 bytes `s[(int)(Math.random()*10)+n%2]` instead of `s[((int)(Math.random()*5))*2+(n%2)]`

Comment: @Dodge right, the outer two parenthesis can be removed. And for your other comment, no i can't do that because `Math.random()*10` and `(Math.random()*5)*2` are two different operations. The first will give you a random number in the range of `0-9`, whereas the second version will give you a random number from `0,2,4,6,8`

Comment: You can save 3 bytes: `(-1+i)` -> `(i-1)`; `i=0;while(i<d.length)` -> `for(i=0;i<d.length;)`; `i=0;while(i<n){` -> `for(i=0;i<n;){`.

Comment: And 4 more bytes by changing `'@'` to `64`; `'('` to `40` and `')'` to `41`. Also, as for the duplicated `"MAF"`, you're also allowed to just have two decorations of length 2 and two of length 3.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for your input. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 233 Bytes

Should be able to golf this down a bit from here...

```
A="HMFMAFCF";i,j,k,t;f(n){t=time();char*S=n&1?t&1?A:A+3:t&1?A+1:A+6;for(;i<n;i++,puts(")"))for(j=0,k=2*n-1,putchar(40);j<k;putchar(0==i*j|i==n-1|j==k-1?64:n&1&i==n/2&j>n-3&j<n+1?*S++:n&1?32:(i==n/2-1|i==n/2)&j>n-2&j<n?*S++:32),j++);}
```

Great challenge, this was difficult and ugly to code.

Run with this main func;

```
main(c,v)char**v;
{
    f(atoi(v[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 386 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pn=
set f=HMAC
set/ao=n%%2,u=n/2,l=h=u+1,d=%random%%%2*2+1
if %o%==1 set/al=u=0,d/=2
set c=
for /l %%i in (4,1,%n%) do call set c= %%c%%
call:l %n%
for /l %%i in (2,1,%n%) do call:l %%i
exit/b
:l
set s=   
if %1==%h% call set s=%%f:~%d%,2%%F
if %1==%u% call set s= %%f:~%d%,1%% 
if %1==%l% set s= F 
set s=(@%c%%s%%c%@)
if %1==%n% set s=%s: =@%
echo %s%
```

Will only output HMF, MAF, MF or CF as appropriate. Note: certain lines end in white space. Variables:

- `n` Input parameter (read from STDIN)
- `f` Decoration prefixes (suffix `F` is implied)
- `o` Oddness of `n` (only used once, but `if` statements don't accept expressions)
- `l` Row of the upper vertical character, or `0` for a horizontal decoration
- `u` Row of the lower vertical character, or `0` for a horizontal decoration
- `h` Row of the horizontal decoration (gets overwritten by a vertical decoration)
- `d` Index of decoration in decoration prefix (0/1 for horizontal or 1/3 for vertical)
- `c` String of `n-3` spaces
- `s` Output string for each row
- `%1` Row number, but set to `n` for the first row too, so that both first and last rows use `@`s instead of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2.3.1, <s>449</s> <s>265</s> <s>245</s> <s>233</s> 230 characters

Seems like there should be a ruby answer, so here is a ruby answer. It's really not that clever, Hopefully someone else here will be more clever ;)

Golfed version:

```
def m(n)
d,s=n.odd?? [[%w{MAF HMF}.sample],n/2]:[%w{RF LF}.sample.chars,(n-2)/2]
r=->f{l=f.size;q=($i-l)/2;($c=' '*$i)[q...l+q]=f;puts "(@#$c@)"}
$i=2*n-1;a='@'*$i
r[a]
(1..n-2).map{|x|(s...s+d.size)===x ?r[d[x-s]]:r['']}
r[a]
end
```

Golfing tricks:

- replace method declaration with a stabby string interpolation of
- $globals doesn't need #{global}, only #$global
- === for ranges is shorter than .covers?

Readable version

```
def row(inner_width, fillchar='')
  padding = ( inner_width - fillchar.size) / 2
  (center =(' ' * inner_width))[padding...fillchar.size+padding]=fillchar
  puts "(@"+center+"@)"
end

def mooncake(n)
  decoration = n.odd?? [%w{ MAF HMF JCJ TTT }.sample] : %w{ ZJ LF RF CF }.sample.chars
  start_row = n.odd?? (n/2) : (n - 2) / 2
  inner_width = 2 * n - 1
  row(inner_width,'@'*inner_width)
  (1...(n-1)).each do |row|
    if (start_row ... start_row + decoration.size).include? row 
      row(inner_width,decoration[row - start_row])      
    else
      row(inner_width)      
    end
  end
  row(inner_width,'@'*inner_width)
end
```

Testing

```
mooncake(3)
mooncake(4)
mooncake(5)
mooncake(6)
```

Comment: I reimplemented w/o using the array, seems like everyone is doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I was bored ... here are two more versions:

## PHP, 193 bytes

```
function p($s){global$n;return"(@".str_pad($s,2*$n-3,$s?" ":"@",2)."@)
";}$p=[M,MA,R,HM][rand()&2|1&$n=$argv[1]];echo p(""),$e=str_repeat(p(" "),($n+$n%2)/2-2),$n&1?p($p.F):p($p).p(F),$e,p("");
```

a port of [Lmis´ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93348#93348)

## PHP, 191 bytes

```
for($p=[M,MA,R,HM][rand()&2|1&$n=$argv[1]].F;$i<$n*$w=2*$n+1;$i++)echo($x=$i%$w)?$w-1-$x?($y=$i/$w|0)%($n-1)&&1-$x&&$w-2-$x?$p[$n&1?$n>>1!=$y?9:$x-$n+1:($n-$x?9:$y-$n/2+1)]?:" ":"@":")
":"(";
```

printing the cake character by character in a single loop

**breakdown**

```
for(
    $p=[M,MA,R,HM][rand()&2|1&$n=$argv[1]].F;   // pick decoration
    $i<$n*$w=2*$n+1;$i++)       // loop $i from 0 to $n*width-1:
echo                                // print ...
    $w-1-($x=$i%$w)                 // 1. not last column
        ?$x                         // 2. not first column
            ?
                ($y=$i/$w|0)%($n-1) // 3. not first or last line
                && 1-$x%($w-3)      // and not second or (width-2)th column
                ?$p[$n&1
                    ?$n>>1!=$y?3:1+$x-$n
                    :($n-$x?3:1+$y-$n/2)
                ]   ?               // 4. decoration character
                    :" "            // 4. else: blank
                :"@"                // 3. else: "@"
            :"("                    // 2. else: "("
        :")\n"                      // 1. else: ")"+newline
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>318</s> <s>301</s> <s>297</s> <s>285</s> 272 bytes

**Knocked off 17 bytes with the help of DJMcMayhem**

**Knocked off 4 bytes thanks to mbomb007**

**Knocked off another 12 bytes thanks to DJMcMayhem**

**Knocked off another 13 bytes thanks to mbomb007**

My first golf ever, so it's not all that great. I used: aliasing math.ceil as y and str.format as z, nesting formats, single line imports, lambda, and bitwise operation plus some other things to get this like it is.

```
def f(n):import random,math;y=math.ceil;z=str.format;i=y(2*n-5>>1);j=y(n-3>>1);return z("{a}{}{a}",z("{d}(@{}{b}F{c}@)\n{e}"," "*i,b=random.sample(["L","R"],1)[0],c=" "*(2*n-5-i),d=z("(@{}@)\n"," "*(2*n-3))*j,e=z("(@{}@)\n"," "*(2*n-3))*(n-3-j)),a=z("({})\n","@"*(2*n-1)))
```

Ungolfed version (separated imports, no aliases, and no bitwise operation):

```
def f(n):
    import random;
    import math;
    return "{a}{}{a}".format(
        "{d}(@{}{b}F{c}@)\n{e}".format(
            " "*(math.ceil((2*n-5)/2)),
            b=random.sample(["L","R"],1)[0],
            c=" "*((2*n)-(5+math.ceil((2*n-5)/2))),
            d="(@{}@)\n".format(" "*(2*n-3))*math.ceil((n-3)/2),
            e="(@{}@)\n".format(" "*(2*n-3))*(n-(3+(math.ceil((n-3)/2))))),
        a="({})\n".format("@"*(2*n-1)))
```

Interestingly, using the non-bitwise version of this still produces correct output, however, the output is different:

Non-Bitwise:

```
(@@@@@@@)
(@     @)
(@  LF @)
(@@@@@@@)
```

Bitwise:

```
(@@@@@@@)
(@ LF  @)
(@     @)
(@@@@@@@)
```

Comment: you can move the imports out of the function and change them to `from ... import*` type imports to save some bytes

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site! A couple tips: 1. lambda functions are shorter, and 2. you could do `import math;y=math.ceil` to take two bytes off. This would give you `import random;import math;y=math.ceil;lambda n:"{a}{}{a}".format("{d}(@{}{b}F{c}@)\n{e}".format(" "*(y((2*n-5)/2)),b=random.sample(["L","R"],1)[0],c=" "*((2*n)-(5+y((2*n-5)/2))),d="(@{}@)\n".format(" "*(2*n-3))*y((n-3)/2),e="(@{}@)\n".format(" "*(2*n-3))*(n-(3+(y((n-3)/2))))),a="({})\n".format("@"*(2*n-1)))` which is 13 bytes shorter.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks a lot! I updated my answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! One other thing you could probably do is alias to `format` since you call it a lot. Problem is, I don't exactly know how to alias to a member function (like `str.format`) so you'd have to experiment a little. I'm not positive it would be shorter though.

Comment: `n-(3+(y((n-3)/2)))` can be shortened to `n-y(n-3>>1)-3`. `(n-3)/2` is `n-3>>1`. `(2*n)-(5+y((2*n-5)/2))` is `2*n-y(2*n-5>>1)-5`.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem This is the best that I could do with using an alias `import random,math;y=math.ceil;z=lambda s,*u,**w:s.format(*u,**w);lambda n:z("{a}{}{a}",z("{d}(@{}{b}F{c}@)\n{e}"," "*(y((2*n-5)/2)),b=random.sample(["L","R"],1)[0],c=" "*((2*n)-(5+y((2*n-5)/2))),d=z("(@{}@)\n"," "*(2*n-3))*y((n-3)/2),e=z("(@{}@)\n"," "*(2*n-3))*(n-(3+(y((n-3)/2))))),a=z("({})\n","@"*(2*n-1)))` it's unfortunately a little longer, perhaps there's an easier way to do it? I only save 5 bytes per format and I used 6, so I need a way to alias format that is 29 or less bytes.

Comment: Well, you could do `f=str.format`, but you'll have to modify some things for it to work right. See [this tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27044/31716)

Comment: @mbomb007 thanks a lot! I was able to knock off four bytes but it slightly altered the output (still correct, just different)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Where was that post when I was looking for an hour and a half... thank you, that worked beautifully.

Comment: @L.Steer Did you even make my suggested changes? Read them and make them again, since you didn't.

Comment: @mbomb007 I did, and then made another change but apparently it was to a different version of the code I had. It's in there now, I've been making lots of edits because it started off pretty sloppy. Thanks again!

Comment: You only made one of the 3 changes I suggested. Look at all 3 changes closely and all the parentheses I removed.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm so sorry, I wasn't reading carefully at all. I've made the rearrangements and also stored the results of the ceiling functions as variables so I was able to shave off 20 bytes! Hopefully I haven't missed other suggestions, but I wouldn't be surprised at this point...

Comment: You can't store those as variables, as `n` isn't defined outside the `lambda`. If you use a function with `def` you can store variables inside, but not in a `lambda`.

Comment: Alright, that's going to be my last edit then, regardless of what modifications I can make. I decided to switch to using a function so that I could store the variables (I'm not used to working with lambdas so that was eye opening for me). This was a very educational exercise, thanks to the both of you for your help.

Comment: Nice work! I am glad you got something out of this exercise :) However, I would like to clarify that the decoration must be centered to fit the challenge specifications. Whether or not you decide to change your code to reflect this - can I ask that you keep the current code in your post too? Good effort worth keeping, even if it neglects one of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

## C# 448 bytes

Golfed:

```
var v=n%2==0;int l=n+n-3,h=n-2,e=v?0:1,c=e+2;var c2=v?"MFZJLFRFCF":"MAFHMFJCJTTT";var r=new Random().Next(3+e);var f=new String(c2.Skip(c*r).Take(c).ToArray());var mc="";for (var i=0;i < h;i++) {var x="";if (!v && i==((h / 2))) { x=f;} else if (v && ((i==h / 2) || (i==(h/2)-1))) { x +=f[i%2==1?0:1];} var es=x.PadLeft((l/2)+1+e,' ').PadRight(l,' ');mc +="(@"+es+"@)\n";}var b="("+"".PadLeft(l+2, '@')+")";mc=b+"\n"+mc+ b; Console.WriteLine(mc);
```

Test it [here](http://rextester.com/EQOSI4698)

Ungolfed:

```
        var v = n % 2 == 0;
        int l = n + n - 3, h = n - 2, e = v ? 0 : 1, c = e + 2;
        var c2 = v ? "MFZJLFRFCF" : "MAFHMFJCJTTT";
        var r = new Random().Next(3 + e);
        var f = new String(c2.Skip(c * r).Take(c).ToArray());
        var mc = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            var x = "";
            if (!v && i == ((h / 2)))
            {
                x = f;
            }
            else if (v && ((i == h / 2) || (i == (h / 2) - 1)))
            {
                x += f[i % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1];
            }
            var emptySpace = x.PadLeft((l / 2) + 1 + e, ' ').PadRight(l, ' ');
            mc += "(@" + emptySpace + "@)\n";
        }
        var b = "(" + "".PadLeft(l + 2, '@') + ")";
        mc = b + "\n" + mc + b;
        Console.WriteLine(mc);
```