# Cheap, Fast, Good - Common Factor (Greatest)

Tags: popularity-contest, number-theory, underhanded

Inspired by [Cheap, Fast, Good](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26782/fast-cheap-and-good-choose-any-two), we're going to implement an algorithm which has exactly two of them.

**The Math**

Given two nonzero integers *a* and *b*, the GCF *d* is the largest integer that divides both *a* and *b* without remainder. [Bézout coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) are pairs of integers *(x, y)* such that *ax + by = d*. Bézout coefficients are not unique. For example, given:

```
a = 15, b = 9
```

We have

```
d =  3
x =  2
y = -3
```

Since `15*2 + 9*(-3) = 30 - 27 = 3`.

A common way to calculate the GCF and a pair of Bézout coefficients is using [Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), but it's by no means the only way.

**The Code**

Your program should take two integers as inputs. It should output/return the greatest common factor and one pair of Bézout coefficients.

Example input:

```
15 9
```

example output

```
3 (2, -3)
```

The output can be in any order and format, but it should be clear which is the GCF and which are the coefficients.

**The Underhanded**

Your program has the potential to be cheap, fast, and good. Unfortunately, it can only be two of those at once.

- When it's not *cheap*, the program should use an excessive amount of system resources.
- When it's not *fast*, the program should take an excessive amount of time.
- When it's not *good*, the program output should be wrong.

The program should be able to do (well, not do) all three. Which is does when is up to you- it could be based on the time, the compiler, which input is larger, etc. Some additional notes:

- Your program should not be obviously underhanded and should pass a cursory inspection. I'd be a little suspicious if you implemented three separate algorithms.
- In the *cheap* case, "excessive amount of system resources" is anything that would slow down other programs. It could be memory, bandwidth, etc.
- In the *fast* case, "excessive time" means relative to how it runs in the *cheap* and *good* cases. The program should still finish. The closer you can to "incredibly frustrating but not frustrating enough to stop the program" the (funnier and) better.
- In the *good* case, the output shouldn't be obviously wrong  and should pass a cursory inspection. I'd be **very** suspicious if it gave me a GCF of "2 anna half".

This is a popularity contest, so most upvotes wins!

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'm looking for programs that can be "fast and cheap" *and* "cheap and good" *and* "fast and good" in different cases, not ones that just do one of them.

Comment: It's nice to have an original challenge like this. :)

Comment: Does the program have to be *exactly* two at once or is it OK if it's only good in some cases and cheap and fast (but not good) in others?

Comment: I'm looking for three cases, with exactly two in each.

Comment: If the program is not good it's output should be incorrect? Then what is the point of calculating anything correctly?

Comment: @RicardoA Because that's only one of the three cases, and this is an underhanded contest, so you're trying to hide the fact that in one of the three cases, it's incorrect.

Comment: @Hovercouch I understand the rules but by looking at some of the answers the fact that the output is wrong is not hidden which makes it not underhanded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an [underhanded] challenge, which was on-topic a year ago, but is now off-topic by [community consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8326/31716).

Answer (score 2):

## C

It's cheap and fast. You get gcd in the blink of an eye. However the guy who did it had no clue about that "Bézier co-something" so he simply divided a and b by gcd.
(to make things worse, at that point a and b are pretty far from their initial value because of the algorithm he wisely chose)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    unsigned int a, b, tmp;
    a = (unsigned int)atoi(argv[1]);
    b = (unsigned int)atoi(argv[2]);
    for (tmp = 0; ((a | b) & 1) == 0; ++tmp){
        a >>= 1;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    while ((a & 1) == 0) 
        a >>= 1;
    do {
        while ((b & 1) == 0)
            b >>= 1;
        if (a > b){
            unsigned int t = b; 
            b = a; 
            a = t;
        }  
        b = b - a;
    } while (b != 0);
    tmp = a << tmp;
    printf("%u, (%u,%u)", tmp, a/tmp, b/tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#

This calculates the Bézout coefficients. I used the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number.");
            int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number.");
            int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            double max = Math.Max(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            double min = Math.Min(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            double s1 = 1;
            double s2 = 0;
            double t1 = 0;
            double t2 = 1;
            double quotient = 0;
            double remainder = 0;
            double[] remainders = new double[0];

            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                quotient = (int)(max / min);
                remainder = max - quotient * min;
                if (remainder > 0)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref remainders, remainders.Length + 1);
                    remainders[i] = remainder;

                }
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    s1 = s1 - quotient * s2;
                    t1 = t1 - quotient * t2;
                }
                else
                {
                    s2 = s2 - quotient * s1;
                    t2 = t2 - quotient * t1;
                }

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    max = min;

                }
                else if (i >= 1)
                {
                    max = remainders[i - 1];
                }


                min = remainder;
                i++;
            } while (remainder > 0);

            Console.WriteLine((remainders[remainders.Length - 1]).ToString() + " " + (i % 2 == 0 ? "(" + s1 + "," + t1 + ")" : "(" + s2 + "," + t2 + ")"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When is this expensive, when is it slow, and when is it bad?

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I will put those values when I have the chance.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

#### Not cheap

Uses a lot of system resources.

```js
function gcf(a, b) {
    var result = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < 100000000 * a && i < 100000000/* Do it a few extra times, just to make sure */ * b; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
            result = i;
        }
    }
    return [result, a / result, b / result];
}
```

#### Not fast

Use a callback, just as an extra failsafe.

```js
function gcf(a, b) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var result = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i < 2 * a && i < 2 * b; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
                result = i;
            }
        }
        alert(result.toString() + " (" + (a / result).toString() + ", " + (b/result).toString() + ")");
    }, 10000);
}
```

#### Not good

Strict limit of `gcf(10, 10)`, just to safe disk space.

```js
function gcf(a, b) {
    var gcfTable = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,3,1],[1,2,1,4,1,2,1,4,1,2],[1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,5],[1,2,3,2,1,6,1,2,3,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1],[1,2,1,4,1,2,1,8,1,2],[1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,9,1],[1,2,1,2,5,2,1,2,1,10]];
    return [gcfTable[a - 1][b - 1], a / gcfTable[a - 1][b - 1], b / gcfTable[a - 1][b - 1]];
}
```

Comment: When is it cheap and fast but not good?

Comment: This answer is cheap, good, but not fast.

Comment: the challenge is to write a program that is each of "not cheap", " not fast ", and " not good " in different circumstances.

Comment: Answer fixed...

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { exit };

print(<<INTRO);
Greatest Common Factor

    goodbye           -- exit the application
    [number] [number] -- compute gcf of both numbers

INTRO

main();
sub main {
    print "> ";
    chomp(local $_ = <STDIN>);

    print "Have a good one.\n" and exit if /goodbye/;

    my @nums = /(-?\d+)/g;
    print "invalid input\n" and return main() if @nums != 2;

    my ($gcf, @coeff) = gcf(@nums);
    unless (grep abs($_) > 99, $gcf, @coeff) {
        select $\,$\,$\, rand for 1..10;
    }

    local $" = ", "; #"
    print "gcf(@nums) = $gcf\n";
    print "bezout coefficients: @coeff\n";
    main();
}

sub gcf {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;

    my @r = ($x, $y);
    my @s = (1, 0);
    my @t = (0, 1);

    my $i = 1;
    while ($r[$i] != 0) {
        my $q = int($r[$i-1] / $r[$i]);
        for (\@r, \@s, \@t) {
            $_->[$i+1] = $_->[$i-1] - $q * $_->[$i];
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return map int(1.01 * $_->[$i-1]), \@r, \@s, \@t;
}

__END__
```

Not cheap: main() is called recursively (filling up the stack) until a "deep recursion" warning is fired by perl which will quit the application due to the __WARN__ handler.

Not fast: When the gcf() algorithms returns correct results, the code just hangs on for a few seconds (select() in main()).

Not good: All results above 99 (or below -99) are incorrect.

All in all not so creative; looking forward to more elegant answers.

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def gcd(x, y):
    l = 0
    if x < y:
        l = x
    else:
        l = y
    for g in reversed(range(l + 1)):
        if x%g == 0 and y%g == 0 and g > 1:
            return g
        else:
            if g == 1:
                return 1

def bezout(x,y,g):
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    k = 0
    if x < y:
        k = y
    else:
        k = x
    for _k in range(k):
        tc = (gcd(x,y) - x*_k)%y
        if tc == 0:
            c1 = _k
            c2 = (gcd(x,y) - y*_k)/x
            return (c1, c2)

gc = gcd(15,9)
be, bf = bezout(9,15,gc)
print("%d (%d, %d)" % (gc, be, bf))
```

This is cheap and fast but it is bad in the fact that the range is capped at the largest input so it may not find a pair of coefficients.

Good puzzle.